# Priority queue with level-based notification in Java

Tags: java, priority-queue

Is there a kind of `PriorityBlockingQueue` in Java that allows waiting (like the `take()` method does) for a certain level of elements instead of one element? I.e. "notify me when the level reaches 500 elements"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have maybe you can extend `PriorityBlockingQueue` for your need. `take()` can return once you have more than 500 elements.

```
private volatile size;

public synchronized void take(){
      while(size<500){
        ........
        .........
      }
}
```

just pseudocode.

Comment: Which notifies me as soon as an element is available. However, I only want to be notified when a definable number of elements (say 500) are available.

Comment: @pmf He said "extend". Which means you write the appropriate logic.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a kind of BlockingPriorityQueue in Java that allows waiting
>   (like the take() method does) for a certain level of elements instead
>   of one element?

**No**. There is a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)